# Does Sample Size affects Mutual Information for Feature Selection?

Tags: feature-selection, mutual-information

There is a dataset with n rows (samples) and p columns (variables/features), the objective is to predict a certain target variable (y). Should n (sample size) matter to the results of pairwise mutual information tests between every feature and y ? Meaning if n is too small or too large, the results can't be trusted ? My intuition says no, but I'm not fully confident.

And is there a good reason, besides domain knowledge, to not exclude a variable that in their test had Mutual Information = 0 ?

Comment: The true (population-level) mutual information does not care about the sample size or even care if you draw samples from the population. However, as you get more observations, you get a tighter bound on the mutual information. You can make this more formal with a confidence interval or a credible interval, same as one might for a correlation coefficient. (And none of this has anything to do with using mutual information for feature selection, which may be of questionable utility.)